# Excel Interop Print

Tags: c#, excel, printing, interop

I need to print a selected area of an excel sheet (which I selected with Range.Select()) using the following print settings:

Printer: Microsoft XPS Document Writer
Print Selection
Landscape Orientation
A4
Normal Margins
Fit Sheet on One Page

How can I achieve this using _Worksheet.PrintOut or _Worksheet.PrintOutEx?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I am assuming that you have set reference to Excel and have already declared your objects like

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlexcel;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range xlRange;
object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
```

This goes in the later part of the code.

```
// Get the current printer
string Defprinter = null;
Defprinter = xlexcel.ActivePrinter;

// Set the printer to Microsoft XPS Document Writer
xlexcel.ActivePrinter = "Microsoft XPS Document Writer on Ne01:";

// Setup our sheet
var _with1 = xlWorkSheet.PageSetup;
// A4 papersize
_with1.PaperSize = Excel.XlPaperSize.xlPaperA4;
// Landscape orientation
_with1.Orientation = Excel.XlPageOrientation.xlLandscape;
// Fit Sheet on One Page 
_with1.FitToPagesWide = 1;
_with1.FitToPagesTall = 1;
// Normal Margins
_with1.LeftMargin = xlexcel.InchesToPoints(0.7);
_with1.RightMargin = xlexcel.InchesToPoints(0.7);
_with1.TopMargin = xlexcel.InchesToPoints(0.75);
_with1.BottomMargin = xlexcel.InchesToPoints(0.75);
_with1.HeaderMargin = xlexcel.InchesToPoints(0.3);
_with1.FooterMargin = xlexcel.InchesToPoints(0.3);

// Print the range
xlRange.PrintOutEx(misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, 
misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);

// Set printer back to what it was
xlexcel.ActivePrinter = Defprinter;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But how did you know "on Ne01"?

Comment: You can find that using `Defprinter = xlexcel.ActivePrinter;` and then printing it in the immediate window. That code will tell you what ever your active printer is. To test it change the printer to XPS and then run the above code.

Comment: I found this way to detect which Ne port to use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424932/how-to-determine-what-ne-port-the-adobe-pdf-printer-is-on. Besides pageSetup.Zoom has to be set to false to make FitToPagesWide/Tall work and use range.ExportAsFixedFormat(XlFixedFormatType.xlTypeXPS, outputPath); instead of PrintOutEx. Maybe you can update your code above :)

Comment: How to automate if user wants to Print from page 3 to Page 7.Any way to Add  _with1.StartPage &  _with1.EndPage ?? Thanks

Comment: I have a excel file and I want to auto change tray of printer when printing this file Excel. How I can do that. Tks

Answer (score 1):

For the 'Fit Sheet on One Page' to work we should also set the Zoom property to false.

// Fit Sheet on One Page

```
_with1.FitToPagesWide = 1;

_with1.FitToPagesTall = 1;

_with1.Zoom = False;
```